# SoapFaultException - extract code and text

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to extract code and text separately from the soap fault listed below. The code that I am using (listed below xml) is printing code and text together.

```
<env:Fault xmlns:env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fault = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>fault:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring>An error occurred. Please check the detail section.</faultstring>
    <detail>
        <e:serviceFault xmlns:e = "http://xml.comcast.com/types">
            <e:messages>
                <e:message>
                    <e:code>ERRORCODE-82828</e:code>
                    <e:text>Error Message.</e:text>
                </e:message>
            </e:messages>
        </e:serviceFault>
    </detail>
</env:Fault>
```

**Code**

```
public void printSoapFaultClientException(SoapFaultClientException e) {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = null;
    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

        transformer.transform(e.getSoapFault().getSource(), result);
        NodeList nl = ((Document)result.getNode()).getElementsByTagName("detail");

    System.out.println(" text content " + ((Element)nl.item(0)).getTextContent());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing it , since it is a fault XML , i have just used a parser to parse the XML and extract a field off it. Also SOAPFaultClientException API's can help you extract the fault reason directly if you want it (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/client/SoapFaultClientException.html)

```
File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\DevelopmentTools\\3.CODE\\SOAP.txt");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String responseStatus = xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='code']/text()", doc);
String responseText = xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='text']/text()", doc);
System.out.println("---> " + responseStatus);
System.out.println("---> " + responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramachandran. The Spring API just returns the faultCode and faultstring and doesn't return the inner code and text.

Comment: The xpath helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I am catching (SoapFaultClientException e) in catch block.
how do i extract inner text ??